# What do non-linear activation functions do at a fundamental level in neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, activation-function

I've been trying to find out what exactly non-linear activation functions do when implemented in a neural network.

I know they modify the output of a neuron, but how and for what purpose?

I know they add non-linearity to otherwise linear neural networks, but for what purpose?

What exactly do they do to the output of each layer? Is it some form of classification?

I want to know what exactly their purpose is within neural networks.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) says that "the activation function of a node defines the output of that node given an input or set of inputs."  [This article](https://medium.com/the-theory-of-everything/understanding-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-9491262884e0) states that the activation function checks whether a neuron has "fired" or not.  I've looked at a bunch more articles and other questions on Stack Overflow as well, but none of them gave a satisfying answer as to what is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's better to have a clear idea on why we use activation functions.

We use activation functions to propagate the output of one layer’s nodes to
the next layer. Activation functions are scalar-to-scalar functions and we use activation functions for hidden neurons in a neural network to introduce non-linearity into the network’s model. So in a simpler level, activation function are used to introduce non-linearity into the network.

**So what is the use of introducing non-linearity**? Before that, non-linearity means that an output cannot be reproduced from a linear combination of the inputs. Therefore without a non-linear activation function in a neural-network, even though it may have hundreds of hidden layers it would still behave like a single-layer perceptron. The reason is whichever the way you sum them, it would only result a linear output.

Anyhow for more deeper level understanding, I suggest you to look at this *[Medium](https://medium.com/the-theory-of-everything/understanding-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-9491262884e0)* post as well as this [video](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/neural-networks-deep-learning/why-do-you-need-non-linear-activation-functions-OASKH) by *Andrew Ng* himself.

From the Andrew Ng's video let me rephrase some important parts below.

> ...if you don't have an activation function, then no matter how many
>   layers your neural network has, all it's doing is just computing a
>   linear activation function. So you might as well not have any hidden
>   layers.
>
> ...it turns out that if you have a linear activation function here and
>   a sigmoid function here, then this model is no more expressive than
>   standard logistic regression without any hidden layer.
>
> ...so unless
>   you throw a non-linear in there, then you're not computing more
>   interesting functions even as you go deeper in the network.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for using non-linear activation functions is to be able to learn non-linear target functions, i.e. learn a non-linear relationship between the inputs and outputs. If a network consists of only linear activation functions, it can only model a linear relationship between the inputs and outputs, which is not useful in almost all applications.

I am by no means an ML expert, so maybe this video can explain it better: https://www.coursera.org/lecture/neural-networks-deep-learning/why-do-you-need-non-linear-activation-functions-OASKH

Hope this helps!